# Comparing values from a multidimentional array using Python

Tags: python

I have an array of numbers:

```
a=  [[0, 0.1667],
 [1, 0.1667],
 [2, 0.25], 
 [3, 0.25],
 [4, 0.167]].
```

Each pair contains numbers and their proportions.

I want to compare a particular number Z with the resulted proportions. Lets assume, Z=0.02.  So I have to iterate through the proportions and compare each proportion with Z and find the number whose proportion falls below Z and print that number only.

I think, the proportions need to sorted from highest to lowest first and then it has be compared with Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting will be helpful if you're dealing with lots of data, then you can just loop until the first element is bigger than `z` and you're done.

However, an easy way for going through all elements would be using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = [[0, 0.1667],
 [1, 0.1667],
 [2, 0.25], 
 [3, 0.25],
 [4, 0.167]]

z = 0.2
print [x for x in a if x[1] < z]
```

This will iterate through all elements in `a` and check if the second number of each element in `a` is less than `z`, if yes, they get added to the new list.

Output:

```
>>> 
[[0, 0.1667], [1, 0.1667], [4, 0.167]]
```

(I chose `z = 0.2`, because with `z = 0.02` the list is empty :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with a single such array with multiple values of Z, then sorting will be helpful. Otherwise simply loop over the array and compare proportions with Z and create your desired list. Sorting the array in this case would be more expensive.

PS: If your question is how to sort the array according to proportions:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]))
```